# Failed upgrade to 16.04 because it failed upgrading a package

Tags: upgrade, package-management

The upgrade is stuck for more than 24 hours. I got the following message:

[image]

What can I do? I tried to purge and reinstall `libc6 2.23-0ubuntu3` 
and got this:

```
@pc:~$ sudo apt-get purge sudo apt-get purge libc6_2.23-0ubuntu3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-get
E: Unable to locate package purge
E: Unable to locate package libc6_2.23-0ubuntu3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libc6_2.23-0ubuntu3'
@pc:~$ sudo apt-get purge libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4.3'
@pc:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug. Have a look at this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1594454

Comment: Any known solution?